# Xml - Bean constructor

Tags: java, xml, constructor, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

i'm using apache camel and i want to instantiate java class in blueprint.xml

this is the constructor of the class:

```
public class ShiroSecurityPolicy implements AuthorizationPolicy {
          private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShiroSecurityPolicy.class);
        private final byte[] bits128 = {
            (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x0B,
            (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0x0F,
            (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x13,
            (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x17};
        private CipherService cipherService;
        private byte[] passPhrase;
        private SecurityManager securityManager;
        private List<Permission> permissionsList;
        private boolean alwaysReauthenticate;
        private boolean base64;

    public ShiroSecurityPolicy(String iniResourcePath, byte[] passPhrase, boolean alwaysReauthenticate, List<Permission> permissionsList)
               {
                     this(iniResourcePath, passPhrase, alwaysReauthenticate); 
                     this.setPermissionsList(permissionsList);

               }
                  ........
```

How can i instantiate it in blueprint.xml ?

this is what i did :

```
<bean id="shiroPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.shiro.security.ShiroSecurityPolicy">
       <argument value="shiro.ini"/>
           ...
</bean>
```

but what i put for passPhrase (which is an Array) and permissionsList (which is a List) argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List:

```
    <argument>
        <list>
            <value>item1</value>
            <value>item2</value>
            <value>item3</value>
        </list>
    </argument>
```

Array:

```
    <argument>
        <array>
            <value>item1</value>
            <value>item2</value>
            <value>item3</value>
        </array>
    </argument>
```

You can use constructor `public ShiroSecurityPolicy(String iniResourcePath)` and inject passPhrase and permissionsList like bean's properties.

If I'm not mistaken, permissionsList can be specified in ini file: http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html

UPDATED:

Try to set permission list like here:

```
   <argument>
       <list>
           <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authz.permission.WildcardPermission">
               <argument value="zone1"/>
           </bean>
       </list>
   </argument>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To create a shiro permission list we use this code : `List<permission> permissionsList = new ArrayList<permission>();
Permission permission = new WildcardPermission("zone1");
permissionsList.add(permission);` How can i call WildcardPermission("zone1") in ShiroSecurityPolicy constructor ?